# How to get just the key of your input in securestore in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, error-handling, syntax-error, mobile-development

I am trying to get just the key from the secureStore in react native, but I don't know how to do it exactly.

Comment: Don't you need to know the key beforehand to get the item? As you used this key to initially set the value against said key. For example, when you call getItemAsync(key) - you must pass a key to get the value, that key was used to set the item.  What is your use case?

Comment: @AleksandarZoric I need the key to know exactly how many items are in my array

Comment: Little confused.  Is that array a value? You can't have an array as a key so it must be a value.  If so, the key you used to set the value/array - use the same key to retrieve the value and count the items in the array.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.